# New-Item : Access to the path '2020_10_19' is denied

Tags: windows, powershell

I have a short script that creates a directory on another server to archive some files.
The script works fine from the command line but I want to use it in a schedule that runs at night under a service account.
This nightly process does a bunch of stuff without fail but the ps script fails with access denied.

```
$today=get-date
#$arcYear=$today.year
$ArchiveRoot="\\bigfiles\k\WebAccessUpLoadArchive\2020Data\"
$ArchiveSourceDir = "\\dataserver\d$\dailyTransfer\*.zip"
$arcDat=$today.AddDays(-1)
$now=$arcDat.tostring('yyyy_MM_dd')
$arcdir=$archiveroot+$Now
New-Item -Path $archiveroot -Name $now -ItemType 'Directory'
```

Answer (score 1):

#### Task Security options

First of all in ***Security options*** of the task you have to set the task is run with admin privileges and with a admin account, and that the task is run whether user is logged  on or not.

[image]

#### Setting Up Action

Then when adding an action to run a PowerShell script use the full path of ***powershell.exe***. On my OS it is ***C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe***. And in arguments besides `-File` argument with the full path of the script you must add `-NoProfile -Executionpolicy bypass` arguments.

[image]

Comment: `Run with highest privileges` is probably unnecessary here. This only needs to run as an account with permission to write to the remote directory. `-NoProfile` and `-ExecutionPolicy Bypass` are optional, depending on the local configuration.